# Implementing If function in UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to understand if it's possible to use a If function within the UserData. When I use the below CloudFormation template, everything executes as expected.

```
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
        <OMIT>
        BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 50
        - !If [VolumeCreationCondition, {DeviceName: xvdh, Ebs:{VolumeSize: 150, VolumeType: st1}}, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
        UserData:
          !Base64 |
            <powershell>
            Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core;
            Initialize-Disk 1;
            New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel Video;
            & "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1" -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c ssm:WindowsAgentConfig
            </powershell>
```

However, when I introduce 2 new If conditions then not a single PowerShell command is ever executed.

```
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
        <OMIT>
        BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 50
        - !If [VolumeCreationCondition, {DeviceName: xvdh, Ebs:{VolumeSize: 150, VolumeType: st1}}, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
        UserData:
          !Base64 |
            <powershell>
            Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core;
            !If [VolumeCreationCondition, Initialize-Disk 1;, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
            !If [VolumeCreationCondition, New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel Video;, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
            & "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1" -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c ssm:WindowsAgentConfig
            </powershell>
```

It is not a problem with the `VolumeCreationCondition` because it works fine here.

```
!If [VolumeCreationCondition, {DeviceName: xvdh, Ebs:{VolumeSize: 150, VolumeType: st1}}, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
```

I am unable to find any syntax issues when referencing [AWS Condition functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if). Is the only solution to my scenario to instead apply the condition to this EC2 resource? This would not be ideal because I have several other resources that reference this EC2, which means I would have to implement conditions on  all of those too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use CloudFormation `IF` statement inside PowerShell script.
In fact inside any `userdata` script.

I don't know about PowerShell, but I will show you how to do what you want with Bash. Just follow the same approach.

```
Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
        <OMIT>
        BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
            Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 50
        - !If [VolumeCreationCondition, {DeviceName: xvdh, Ebs:{VolumeSize: 150, VolumeType: st1}}, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
        UserData:
            Fn::Base64: !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            
            export need_to_init="${VolumeCreationCondition}"
            if [[ "${need_to_init}" != "" ]]
            then
                # "Run your command to init disk here"
            fi
```

You can't use CloudFormation condition inside your userdata script directly.
See below an example trying to use it.

```
Parameters:
  Production:
    Type: String
    Default: ''

Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Not [!Equals [!Ref Production, '']]

Resources:
  CloudNetPingTargetInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210427.0-x86_64-gp2
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: '0'
          DeleteOnTermination: true
          SubnetId: subnet-11111c86
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash

          export PRODUCTION="${CreateProdResources}"
          if [[ "$PRODUCTION" != "" ]]
          then
            echo "##### IS PRODUCTION"
          fi
```

See what happens when we validate template:

```
$ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://test.yaml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [CreateProdResources] in the Resources block of the template
```

But you can perform the same kind of logic you did with CloudFormation condition inside your script. See it below.

```
Parameters:
  Production:
    Type: String
    Default: ''

Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Not [!Equals [!Ref Production, '']]

Resources:
  CloudNetPingTargetInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210427.0-x86_64-gp2
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: '0'
          DeleteOnTermination: true
          SubnetId: subnet-11111c86
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash

          export PRODUCTION="${Production}"
          if [[ "$PRODUCTION" != "" ]]
          then
            echo "##### IS PRODUCTION"
          fi
```

Now when I validate, it works.

```
$ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://test.yaml
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "ParameterKey": "Production",
            "DefaultValue": "",
            "NoEcho": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The trick is to use CloudFormation `Sub` function to create a script variable with value from CloudFormation parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this got me headed into the correct direction. I used the same logic of defining variables within the powershell script, and did the if statement using powershell syntax. It's working properly now.